# All solutions to $1/a+1/b=1/c$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, conjectures

Conjecture:
Given integers $a>b>c>1$ such that $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$. Then all the positive integer solutions to
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{c}$$
is given by: $c$ any number and for each divisor $d<\sqrt{c}\:$ of $\,c\,$ with $\gcd(d,c/d)=1$
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l} a_d=c+d^2 \\ 
b_d=\frac{c}{d}\cdot(\frac{c}{d}+d)=c\cdot(c+d^2)/d^2
\end{array} \right. $$
It is easy to show that $a_d,b_d,c$ all are solutions, but how to prove they are the only solutions?

Comment: You need additional conditions on $d$ to ensure the gcd condition. Namely, $\gcd(d,c/d)=1.$

Comment: If $p\mid \gcd(d,c/d),$ you still get $p\mid\gcd(a,b,c).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are such that $a>b>c>1$ amd $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ and $\tfrac1a+\tfrac1b=\tfrac1c$, then aso
$$bc+ac=ab.\tag{1}$$
This shows that $c$ divides $ab$, and similarly $a$ divides $bc$ and $b$ divides $ac$. Let $w=\gcd(a,b)$ and $v=\gcd(a,c)$ and $u=\gcd(b,c)$. Then $u$, $v$ and $w$ are pairwise coprime positive integers with $w>v>u$, and
$$a=vw,\qquad b=uw,\qquad c=uv.$$
Plugging this into $(1)$ shows that $w=u+v$, and so every solution is of the form
$$a=v(u+v),\qquad b=u(u+v),\qquad c=uv,$$
with $v>u>0$ coprime.
Conversely, for any two coprime positive integers $v>u$ you have
$$\frac{1}{v(u+v)}+\frac{1}{u(u+v)}=\frac{1}{uv}.$$
This shows that these are precisely all solutions.

This is equivalent to your characterization; take $d=u$ and $c=uv$.

Comment: Feel free to explain the downvote.

Comment: Interesting! Is this a special case of my conjecture?

Comment: “It follows that…” How? Doesn’t seem immediately obvious to me.

Comment: However, your equation can be seen as $$(a-c)(b-c)=c^2.$$ So yo need a factorization of $c^2$ into relatively prime factors, which is the same as factoring $c$ into relatively prime factors, $c=uv ,$ $u,v$ relatively prime, with $u<v.$ Then you get $b=u^2+uv,a=v^2+uv,$ which is your answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That was a bit of a leap indeed. I have added an intermediate step. I also like your approach.

Comment: @Lehs It is a proof of your conjecture.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Glad you had time to answer before the question was closed. Thanks!

Comment: Why a=gcd(a,b)gcd(a,c) ? If we multiply a by a factor relatively prime with u, nu and w, the gcd do not change, but the relation between a and the gcd's is not valid any longer. Am I missing smth?

Comment: @Thomas Because $a$ divides $bc$ we have $a=\gcd(a,bc)$. Because $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ we have $\gcd(a,bc)=\gcd(a,b)\gcd(a,c)$.

Comment: I see you use the previous observation that a divides bc. Thanks!